# Is it possible to attach one role to a redshift cluster and use that for all access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I don't like having to specify specific roles in each command.

Is there a way I can just attach a single role to my redshift cluster and have every command (like the copy command) just use that role and not have to specify an `iam_role` in every command?

It seems weird to me because I can attach a role to an EC2 instance and it will just give anything calling the AWS apis on that sever that access.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're doing? something like this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

**Amazon Redshift** needs to know which IAM Role to use when accessing data from Amazon S3. This is specified via the `iam_role` parameter. Roles attached to the Redshift cluster are merely *referenced*, rather than credentials being provided as part of the query.

This is quite different to the **Amazon EC2** situation, where the AWS CLI and AWS SDKs always look in the user's `~/.aws/credentials` file to obtain credentials for use with API calls. There is no capability to provide such credentials in Amazon Redshift.

It is also quite different to the way **Amazon Athena** handles permissions. Athena uses the S3 permissions of the user who runs the query.

Comment: I think you can do all this with just one role. Do not need different roles for different use-cases.